# Generics and Inheritance: How to use the parent in the child class?

Tags: c#, silverlight, generics, inheritance, architecture

I just try to redesign my Silverlight-4 App and tried a bit around with generics.

Simply speaking, I have a tree which can contain 2 types of nodes. As a base class, I created a class that does all the "organization", like having a list of children, a parent, a method to add a child and so on:

```
public abstract class BaseNode<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T: BaseNode<T>
{
  protected ObservableCollection<T> _children;
  ...
}
```

Second, I add a class that inherits from BaseNode and is the basis for **all** my treenodes:

```
public class ServiceNodeBase<T> : BaseNode<ServiceNodeBase<T>> where T : ServiceNodeBase<T>
{
  public string Description { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

And finally, as I can have two different kinds of nodes, I create a class for each kind, i.e.:

```
public class ServiceNodeComponent<T> : ServiceNodeBase<ServiceNodeComponent<T>> where T : ServiceNodeComponent<T>
{
  public HashSet<Attributes> Attributes { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

In the **ServiceNodeComponent**, I need a method, that scans the tree i.e. to get all the child nodes, that are of the Type **ServiceNodeComponent**. When parsing the tree, I need to use the parent-type of ServiceNodeComponent (ServiceNodeBase), because the child nodes can also be of the **other** type.

Now, I do not know how to instantiate the ServiceNodeBase-Variable.

```
public HashSet<ServiceNodeComponent<T>> GetAllChildComponents()
{
  // declaring the container for the found Components is no problem
  HashSet<ServiceNodeComponent<T>> resultList = new HashSet<ServiceNodeComponent<T>>();
  // but now: how to declare the container for the ServiceBaseNodes?
  HashSet<ServiceNodeBase<???>> workingList = new HashSet<ServiceNodeBase<???>>();
```

Any ideas, how I would implement this?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see anything that justifies using generics. IMHO you should stop worrying about generics and rethink your design.

Comment: As I said in the first sentence, I am just about to redesign and tried to use generics to solve the following problem (just an example): In the base class, there is a method NodeByName(string name) which gives the node with the given name from the tree. Now, the return value is always of the base class type, not of the derived one. With the generics, I could define the return type as T -> so it would be the correct inherited type and I would not need to cast. So, hints for the design-rethinking besides generic is most welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the constraint. It would work if you change it to

```
public class ServiceNodeComponent<T> : ServiceNodeBase<ServiceNodeComponent<T>> 
    where T : ServiceNodeBase<T> {

    public HashSet<ServiceNodeComponent<T>> GetAllChildComponents() {
        // ...
        HashSet<ServiceNodeBase<T>> workingList = new HashSet<ServiceNodeBase<T>>();
        // ...
    }
}
```